# Matching N digits using binaries

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I have a packet coming from a socket which is composed by two subsections, the first composed by 4 numerical digits and the latter composed by 16 alphanumerica digits.

How can I bind the packet coming from the socket using binaries and pattern matching?

For example if I receive:

```
1234th58i4kr04o3
```

I would like to obtain:

```
Packet1 = 1234
Packet2 = "th58i4kr04o3"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using Erlang [bit syntax](http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/bit_syntax.html) and binary pattern matching:

```
<<A:4/binary, Rest/binary>> = <<"1234th58i4kr04o3">>, 
Packet1 = binary_to_integer(A), 
Packet2 = binary_to_list(Rest).
```

Comment: "literally achieve" ?